# How to sync scroll with multiple UIScrollViews?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have 2 UIScrollViews displaying an image each (overview and zoom mode). I can scroll in both views already individually, now I want to keep the centerpoint of both views in sync.

I guess when one of the views is creating events, I need to forward them also to the other view, just can't find out which functions are relevant. Any hints?

edit: If parallel live scrolling is not possible, I want to at least sync after a scroll event.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out the functions

- [-setContentOffset:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/setContentOffset%3aanimated%3a)
- [-contentOffset](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/setContentOffset%3aanimated%3a)
- [-zoomScale](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/setContentOffset%3aanimated%3a)
- [-setZoomScale:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/setContentOffset%3aanimated%3a)
- [-zoomToRect:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/setContentOffset%3aanimated%3a)

You can link this together in the delegate method [-scrollViewDidScroll:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate), which is constantly called while the user is scrolling.

Comment: thank you, works really great!

    - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if(scrollView==v1) { v2.contentOffset = v1.contentOffset; }
    else if(.......

Answer (score 3):

This is not specific to the requirement here but helps in syncing scrollViews among different classes.

To sync scrollViews between different classes, use NSNotificationCenter to observe for a particular notification.

When scroll occurs then within the **-scrollViewDidScroll:** delegate method, use **NSNotificationCenter** to post the notification (with **userInfo** contents as **scrollView.contentOffset.x** & **scrollView.contentOffset.y**)
Example:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[userInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:scrollView.contentOffset.x]
          forKey:@"offsetX"];
[userInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:scrollView.contentOffset.y]
          forKey:@"offsetY"];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"scrollSync"
                                      object:nil
                                      userInfo:userInfo];
}
```

---

Register for this notification in the same class or anyother class and perform the **-setContentOffset:** method on the scrollView/s you want synced.
.
**Example on Adding Observer** (either in didLoad or init or anywhere suitable to you in as many classes as you like):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(handleNotification:)
                                      name:@"scrollSync" object:nil];
```

.
**Example of the Selector Method**

```
-(void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)sender
{
float newX = [[sender.userInfo objectForKey:@"offsetX"] floatValue];
float newY = [[sender.userInfo objectForKey:@"offsetY"] floatValue];

[myOtherScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(newX,newY)];
}
```